# how to Edit a particular id in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which is showing around 3000 entries. what i am trying to do is when i click on filter button the data of only that entry will change. but currently, when i click on filter button the data of all the entries are changing.

here is my code:-

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM inventory_details where status ='0' limit 0,100";  
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $inventorybackground = $row['inventorybackground'];
    $inventorycolor = $row['inventorycolor'];
    $firm_name = $row['firm_name'];
    $position = $row['position'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $catagory_name = $row['catagory_name'];
    $supplier = $row['supplier'];

    if (isset($_POST['update'])){
        $position=$_POST['position'];

        $update_query="UPDATE inventory_details SET position ='$position' WHERE id='$id'";
        $run_update=mysqli_query($conn, $update_query);
    }
  ?>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: <?php echo $inventorybackground; ?> !important; color: <?php echo $inventorycolor; ?>; padding-top: 10px;">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col-md-1 inventory-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 inventory-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firm_name" name="firm_name" value="<?php echo $firm_name;?>" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 inventory-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position" value="<?php echo $position;?>">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1 inventory-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $city;?>" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 inventory-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="catagory_name" name="catagory_name" value="<?php echo $catagory_name;?>" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 inventory-data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="supplier" name="supplier" value="<?php echo $supplier;?>" disabled>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 inventory-data">
          <button type="submit" name="update" value="update" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
```

Currently, i am only trying to change the position and I think, this problem  is because of loop.

Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course all entries are changing - because you perform an UPDATE for every single row that you are looping over here. This UPDATE has no place being inside that loop in the first place. You are not passing any specific ID value back from your form to the script either.

Comment: And IDs must be unique within an HTML document, so by outputting this in a loop you are creating invalid HTML to begin with.

Comment: is there a way to resolve this issue ? If yes, please help me out

Comment: You are performing an update on your list loop, your filter button only refreshes the page to update the entire list.

Comment: yes dude I know, please help me to resolve this problem, thanks

Comment: I just gave you feedback on what you are doing wrong here … so _address_ that feedback, try and modify your script accordingly, and report back how far you get with that. _“please help me to resolve this problem”_ - that’s what we are trying to do, now you need to do _your_ part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, the entire list is updated on your loop to list the rows.

Add this code at your page to detect the form POST to do the update:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {     
    // perform update here
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];

    $update_query="UPDATE inventory_details SET position ='$position' WHERE id='$id'";
    $run_update=mysqli_query($conn, $update_query);
}
```

**Edit:**

Your input can't be disabled, try to use `input hidden` to pass id to POST:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
```

If you need to show the id on input text, change the name to different name istead of `id`, because it will be used from input hidden

Comment: showing error,  Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\xampp\htdocs\sort_inventory.php on line 18

Comment: on this line,  $id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: thanks dude, it worked and my code is also working fine after replacing <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" disabled>

Comment: i dont even think that disabled may cause problem

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
```

This has ending bracket on the end. So you are basically looping through all the data and updating it all. Do the update query outside of loop.

```
    $update_query="UPDATE inventory_details SET position ='$position' WHERE id='$id'";
```

You have SQL injection vulnerability here, please use prepared statements.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
If id is integer, you dont have to put quotation marks around it

Comment: @dm707 oh sorry, i missed that one :D fixed